# GCE Persistent Disk block sized writes data integrity

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, block-device

The block size for a SSD Persistent Disk appears to be 4096 bytes.

If I write aligned blocks of 4096 bytes directly to the block device (/dev/sdb with O_DIRECT and posix_memalign), are these writes going to be atomic?

What I want is for the write call to either successfully write the whole 4K block or not write anything.

Can I end up with 100 bytes from the new write and the rest being old data?

Answer (score 1):

Check out O_ATOMIC which works in conjuction with O_DIRECT to accomplish that. See https://lwn.net/Articles/573092/.

Answer (score 0):

There is no common agreement over whether single sector sized writes are atomic or not with respect to disk power loss - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015068/4513656 for discussion on this point. At least from a SCSI perspective, single LBA single sector atomicity is the expected behaviour (see http://www.t10.org/pipermail/t10/2011-November/016011.html ) but be aware that the Linux block layer can merge/split requests and deals with more than SCSI devices.

It's also worth noting that for SCSI devices there are explicit T10 commands (e.g. `WRITE ATOMIC`) that explicitly guarantee atomicity but devices don't have to implement them and Linux doesn't expose them through regular block device operations. The patches for the `O_ATOMIC` flag referenced in another answer were not in a mainline kernel at the time of writing (February 2017 kernel 4.10) and the flag isn't mentioned in the [open(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

If the system/disk never crashes then yes, a single LBA write of a single sector should appear atomic with regard to a single LBA read of that same single sector.

Note that using `O_DIRECT` does not imply the write made it to non-volatile storage so again after crash you may find acknowledged data is not there. You would need to use `fsync` or `O_SYNC` for further stability guarantees even though you're using a block device.